# Hibernate - Column "name" not found

Tags: hibernate, grails

I added a new Domain class (table) in my web application. Everything works find in a local, but when I tried to deploy the application I have this error:
URI: /myApp/MyDomain/list
Class: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException
Message: "Column "THIS_.TC_STATE_DATE" not found; SQL statement: select this..."

Domain:

```
class MyDomain{

String param1
String param2

Date tcStateDate

String toString(){
    return "${param1}"
  }

static constraints = {

   param2(nullable:true,blank:true)  

 }
}
```

DataSource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
pooled = true
driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
username = "sa"
password = ""
}
hibernate {

cache.use_second_level_cache = true
cache.use_query_cache = false
cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}

environments {

development {

    dataSource {

        dbCreate = "update"//"create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:myApp_prodDb;MVCC=TRUE"

    }
}
test {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:h2:myApp_testDb;MVCC=TRUE"
    }
}
production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:h2:myApp_prodDb;MVCC=TRUE"
        pooled = true
        properties {
           maxActive = -1
           minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
           numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
           testOnBorrow=true
           testWhileIdle=true
           testOnReturn=true
           validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you deploy it where? How are you updating your scheme? Can you post the contents of DataSource.groovy?

Comment: I edited my poste, I deploy it in Tomcat

Comment: I guess table can not be altered (to add column) because tcStateDate is not nullable,( so default value need to be specified for that column). Of course you can run your application with dbCreate = "create" option and new table will be created, but you will lost old data

Comment: Yes That's what I did...no choice :(

Comment: Hibernate will add new columns when using dbCreate='update', but if the property is not-null, it will add a nullable column to avoid making older rows invalid. You then need to update older data with sensible values and update the column to be not-null. Of course this isn't the best approach - using the http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration is a better option.